# Python Pool runs more than n workers at a time and program exits before all threads are done executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, python-multithreading

The program is supposed to use the translate-python API to translate ENGLISH_DICT into 60+ languages (ENGLISH_DICT has been shorted a lot and so has LANG_CODES). Translating a huge dictionary into 60+ languages takes a little close to 2 hours with synchronized coding which is why I wanted to use threads.

My thread pool is supposed to be size 4, but I sometimes get 10 threads running without the previous threads completing (Found this out by putting a print statement on the first and last line of the thread handler). Also, the pool will run multiple threads, but as soon as a few threads complete the entire program terminates and I get a 0 exit code. Lastly, if my max pool size is 10 and I have less than 10 threads join then the program terminated immediately.

More than 4 threads running without previous threads completing
[image]

Only 8 threads finished running out of 65 that were scheduled to run
[image]

9 threads were created but the max thread pool size is 10. The threads started to run but main program exited with a 0 exit code
[image]

```
import copy
import os
import json
import threading
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from queue import Queue
from translate import Translator
LANG_CODES = {"af", "ar", "bn", "bs", "bg", "yue", "ca", "fi", "fr"}
VERIFIED_LANGUAGES = {'en', 'es', 'zh'}
TOTAL_TRANSLATIONS = len(LANG_CODES) - len(VERIFIED_LANGUAGES)
NUM_OF_THREADS = 100
DIR_NAME = 'translations'

#Iterate through nested dictionaries and translate string values
#Then prints the final dictionary as JSON

def translate(english_words: dict, dest_lang: str) -> str:
    stack = []
    cache = {}
    T = Translator(provider='microsoft', from_lang='en', to_lang=dest_lang, secret_access_key=API_SECRET1)
    translated_words = copy.deepcopy(english_words)

    ##Populate dictionary with top-level keys or translate top-level words
    for key in translated_words.keys():
        value = translated_words[key]

        if type(value) == dict:
            stack.append(value)
        else:
            if value in cache:
                translated_words[key] = cache[key]
            else:
                translation = T.translate(value)
                translated_words[key] = translation
                cache[translation] = translation


    while len(stack):
        dic = stack.pop()

        for key in dic.keys():
            value = dic[key]

            if type(value) == dict:
                stack.append(value)
            else:
                if value in cache:
                    dic[key] = cache[value]
                else:
                    # print('Translating "' + value +'" for', dest_lang)
                    translation = T.translate(value)
                    # print('Done translating "' + value +'" for', dest_lang)

                    # print('Translated', value, '->', translation)
                    cache[translation] = translation
                    dic[key] = translation

    return json.dumps(translated_words, indent=4)

##GENERATES A FOLDER CALLED 'translations' WITH LOCALE JSON FILES IN THE WORKING DIRECTORY THE SCRIPT IS LAUNCHED IN WITH MULTIPLE THREADS WORKING ON DIFFERENT LANGUAGES
def generate_translations(english_dict: dict):
    if not os.path.exists(DIR_NAME):
        os.mkdir(DIR_NAME)

    finished_langs = set(map(lambda file_name: file_name.split('.json')[0], os.listdir(DIR_NAME)))
    LANG_CODES.difference_update(finished_langs)

    pool = Pool(NUM_OF_THREADS)
    thread_params = [(english_dict, lang_code) for lang_code in sorted(LANG_CODES) if not lang_code.split('-')[0] in VERIFIED_LANGUAGES]
    pool.map_async(thread_handler, thread_params)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('DONE GENERATING')

##TRANSLATES AN ENTIRE DICTIONARY AND THEN WRITES IT TO A FILE IN THE TRANSLATION FOLDER
def thread_handler(params: tuple):
    english_dict, lang_code = params

    print('Translating for lang_code: ', lang_code)
    translated_string_json = translate(english_dict, lang_code)
    print('done getting string for', lang_code)
    file = open(DIR_NAME + '/' + lang_code + '.json', 'w')
    file.write(translated_string_json)
    file.close()
    num_of_langs_remaining = TOTAL_TRANSLATIONS - len(os.listdir(DIR_NAME))
    print('Done translating for lang_code: ' + lang_code +'.', num_of_langs_remaining, 'remaining.\n\n')


ENGLISH_DICT = {
  "changePassword": {
    "yourCurrentPassword": "Your current password",
    "newPassword": "New password",
    "reenterNewPassword": "Re-enter new password",
    "changePassword": "Change Password",
    "yourProfile": "Your Profile",
    "emptyFieldAlert": {
      "header": "All fields must not be empty",
      "body": "Please fill in all the fields"
    }
  }
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_translations(ENGLISH_DICT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Threads in Python are not equal to Threads in e.g. Java.
They don't actually use multiple CPU cores to execute your code parallel.
Multiprocessing is used instead.

*multiprocessing.dummy* just uses the API from multiprocessing but is actually a wrapper for *threading*.
You should use

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

instead for actual parallelization and better performance.

You should count the amount of threads with

```
print(len(active_children()))
```

If you don't use the *AsyncResult* or a callback then you should just use

```
map(thread_handler, thread_params)
```

instead of

```
map_async(thread_handler, thread_params)
```

because it works parallel anyway and even blocks until it completes the given task.

The context manager protocol also works with Pool:

```
with Pool(NUM_OF_THREADS) as pool:
    thread_params = [(english_dict, lang_code) for lang_code in sorted(LANG_CODES) if not lang_code.split('-')[0] in VERIFIED_LANGUAGES]
    pool.map(thread_handler, thread_params)
print('DONE GENERATING')
```